# How to get the exact text from Edit Text and set into text view in android

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

My problem is this I want to get exact text from Edit text with font that set in Edit text as well as Text size,text color and text style like bold, italic and underline.

till now i used Spannable like this  `Spannable messageText;` and get the text from EditText like this

```
 messageText = editText.getText();
```

and set into textview

```
 textView.setText(messageText);
```

But in this case it return only the simple string not `color,font,size and style`.

```
EditText

   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:tag="no"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:typeface="normal" />

TextView

<TextView
            android:id="@+id/preview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:typeface="normal" />
```

Help me, Thanks

Comment: In xml file set the attribute for textview as same as in your edit text..

Comment: create programatically color,font,size and style for editText,and when the fetching the data from the editText set all the created attributes to the textView where you are passing the string of editText

Comment: @Subburaj no it is  not changing all the attribute of textview

Comment: Can u post your xml having this Edittext and textview??

Comment: @nick i already set programatically color,font,size and style for editText. but i don't know how to set all these value for text view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are setting the background color of the edit text like this

```
 editText.setBackgroundDrawable(new PaintDrawable(Color.YELLOW));
```

Then,

**Do this to get the background color.**

```
PaintDrawable drawable = (PaintDrawable) editText.getBackground();
int color = drawable.getPaint().getColor();
```

**And then set this color to the textView.**

```
textView.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

Comment: i solved my problem just get the color,size and font from the edit text and set into the textview. thanks and happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have ran sample project for you..I think you are expecting this answer..

This is xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:tag="no"
        android:textColor="#1DA237"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:typeface="normal" />


    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/preview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="subbu"
            android:textColor="#1DA237"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:typeface="normal" 
            android:paddingBottom="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/message"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:layout_marginRight="29dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="93dp"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/preview"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity code:

```
 final EditText text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.message);

        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.preview);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                t.setText(text.getText().toString());

            }
        });
```

I think this is what you are expecting.